# How to store images to file system (on internet) and store the paths to the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, filesystems

We are trying to create a site for wallpapers so that would be somehow large files(2mb-5mb) so we'll be needing to store the images on the disk space instead in the database and only the paths to the database. So if you can give some ideas on how to do that (the method we know for now is creating a PHP script with the upload function and by manually selecting the images from the PC to be uploaded) unless you guys would have other suggestions. Tutorials will be much appreciated. Thanks a lot!

This is for the admins to add images not for the users. 
Note: we haven't developed any script so this is to get some ideas from you guys on what we can use with this, if none guess we will just go with the php script.

Comment: Have you tried nothing? Googling for tutorials? Writing some lines? Try to create scaffolds so we can help you finding an appropriate solution.

Comment: You should do it just like you suggested. If you encounter problems, come back and ask for help, and please include a code example then.

Comment: so is that the best method to upload the files?

Comment: (I was trying to get other ideas before working on the method I know)

Comment: you may want to consider to save the file into an separate table with as field an BLOB. the file system doesn't respect database rollbacks (InnoDB only) when you update/delete/insert. this way you should get phantom files on your filesystem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your form,**

```
<form action="PHP_FILE_PATH.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**The PHP Part**

```
<?php
if($_FILES['image']['name'])
{
  $save_path="FOLDER_PATH_TO_SAVE_UPLOADED_IMAGE"; // Folder where you wanna move the file.
  $myname = strtolower($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); //You are renaming the file here
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $save_path.$myname); // Move the uploaded file to the desired folder
}

$inser_into_db="INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`folder_name`, `file_name`) VALUES('$save_path', '$myname'))";

?>
```

Comment: And as @Paul said here in another answer make sure you generate the name for each file on your own in some logic say for example PHP microtime, and use it in the `$myname` variable. The answer I typed here is just a simple example.

Answer (score 6):

For each file uploaded, generate a UUID and use that for the filename on disk. That avoids collisions, sanitizing filenames and path traversal vulnerabilities.

You'll have a table like this: `(id, description, filename)` with values like `(1, "Green field", "0D729DCD-5116-4480-81CE-90A0380B557A.png")`.

Next, you want to avoid the problem of having too many files in one folder — you'll hit a filesystem limitation for many FSes.

To work around this problem, create directories based on the first few letters of the filename. For `0D729DCD-5116-4480-81CE-90A0380B557A.png`, you would store it in `/0/D/7/0D729DCD-5116-4480-81CE-90A0380B557A.png`.

Comment: thanks a lot @Paul, I think I can use folder names like by month or something instead of first letter, but great suggestion.